# How styling and set good position of component RasaHQ/chatroom in angular application

Tags: javascript, css, angular, react-native

I want use this component https://github.com/RasaHQ/chatroom with angular.I added .css and .js files. The component is available on page, but not look good. I want change position of component. Should I change something in css or in react component also?

index.html from angular

```
<body>
<div class="chat-container"></div>
<script src="assets/js/chatreact/Chatroom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var chatroom = new window.Chatroom({
    host: "http://localhost:5005",
    title: "Financial Demo",
    container: document.querySelector(".chat-container"),
    welcomeMessage: "Hi, how may I help you?"
    // speechRecognition: "en-US",
    // voiceLang: "en-US"
  });
  chatroom.openChat();
</script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Current position:
[position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJTTo.png)

Expected position:
[Expected position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF3ZI.png)

```
.chatroom {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  color: #343d4e;
  /*max-height: 90vh;*/
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); }
  .chatroom * {
    box-sizing: border-box; }
  .chatroom.closed {
    height: 40px; }
  .chatroom h3 {
    background-color: #343d4e;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer; }
  .chatroom .chats {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }
    .chatroom .chats .chat {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      position: relative;
      padding: 5px 13px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      list-style: none;
      float: left;
      clear: both;
      margin: 10px 0 0 0;
      max-width: 90%; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat img {
        max-width: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat.left {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat.right {
        float: right;
        clear: both;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat .text {
        word-wrap: break-word; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat.chat-img {
        padding: 5px; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3498db; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat ul,
      .chatroom .chats .chat ol {
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 1.5em; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat ul li,
      .chatroom .chats .chat ol li {
        padding-left: 0; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat.waiting {
        margin: 10px 0;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 0; }

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1; }
  to {
    opacity: 0.3; } }
        .chatroom .chats .chat.waiting span {
          font-size: 1.5em;
          animation-name: fade;
          animation-duration: 0.8s;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-direction: alternate;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; }
        .chatroom .chats .chat.waiting span:nth-child(1) {
          animation-delay: 0s; }
        .chatroom .chats .chat.waiting span:nth-child(2) {
          animation-delay: 0.4s; }
        .chatroom .chats .chat.waiting span:nth-child(3) {
          animation-delay: 0.8s; }
    .chatroom .chats .time {
      list-style: none;
      clear: both;
      height: 10px;
      font-size: 10px;
      color: #414141;
      margin: 5px 0 20px 0; }
      .chatroom .chats .time.left {
        float: left; }
      .chatroom .chats .time.right {
        float: right; }
    .chatroom .chats .chat-buttons {
      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      list-style: none;
      clear: both;
      margin: 10px 0;
      text-align: center; }
      .chatroom .chats .chat-buttons .chat-button {
        display: inline-block;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 3px;
        background-color: #343d4e;
        color: white;
        border: 2px solid white;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        border-radius: 5px; }
        .chatroom .chats .chat-buttons .chat-button:hover, .chatroom .chats .chat-buttons .chat-button.chat-button-selected {
          background-color: rgba(52, 61, 78, 0.6);
          color: white; }
        .chatroom .chats .chat-buttons .chat-button.chat-button-disabled {
          color: grey;
          border: 2px solid grey; }
  .chatroom .input {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background-color: #343d4e;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center; }
    .chatroom .input input[type="text"] {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      outline: 0;
      border: 1px solid white;
      border-right: none;
      color: #343d4e;
      padding: 0 5px;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
      height: 30px;
      flex: 4;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 14px;
      transition: background-color 0.2s ease; }
      .chatroom .input input[type="text"]:focus {
        box-shadow: none;
        background-color: white; }
    .chatroom .input input[type="submit"] {
      display: inline-block;
      background: #343d4e;
      border: 1px solid white;
      color: white;
      height: 30px;
      min-width: 70px;
      line-height: 1;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      flex: 1;
      box-shadow: none;
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      outline: none;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-transform: uppercase; }
      .chatroom .input input[type="submit"]:hover {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); }
  .chatroom #speech-input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background: #343d4e;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease; }
    .chatroom #speech-input:hover {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); }
  .chatroom .vertical-center {
    vertical-align: middle; }


/*# sourceMappingURL=/Chatroom.css.map */
```

Comment: You want your chatbox on the bottom-right side od the screen?

Comment: @KetanRamteke Exacally and over other things.

Comment: checked given answer?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you

Comment: welcome, happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `chat-container` following style:

```css
chat-container {
    width: 360px;
    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3em black;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Set other properties such as `width`, `height` etc according to your choice.

Screenshot:

[image]

[Live Example](https://l802l.csb.app)

Its Code Sandbox Link: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-morning-l802l?file=/src/App.js:449-675)

PS: I am assuming `chat-container` is the one holding the chat-box.
Example: